# calculator add decimal button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, decimal

I'm really new in coding, so please don't judge me. I found solutions to my problem, but still 
didn't understand it.

I need to add a decimal button, I tried adding it as a separate IBAction, or adding it to an existing, but something is going wrong all the time.

What I need is that my - (IBAction)dot:(id)sender button, to perform an action of adding a decimal point, for example i want to enter 334.21 or 1.65, so I could perform operations with this value.

Need an advice in my situation. Thanks a lot.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
    double x, y;
    NSInteger operation;
    BOOL xFlag, yFlag;
} 

- (IBAction)clearAll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)inverseSign:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dot:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)digit:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)operation:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m file

```
#import "mainViewController.h"

@interface mainViewController ()

@end

@implementation mainViewController

enum{
    OP_PLUS     = 101,
    OP_MINUS    = 102,
    OP_MULT     = 103,
    OP_DIV      = 104
};

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (IBAction)clearAll:(id)sender {

    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    xFlag = NO;
    yFlag = NO;

    [self showScreen];
}

- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender {

    x = 0;
    [self showScreen];
}

- (IBAction)inverseSign:(id)sender {

    x = -x;
    [self showScreen];
}

- (IBAction)dot:(id)sender {

   // ???
}

- (IBAction)digit:(id)sender {

    if (xFlag) {
        y = x;
        x = 0;
        xFlag = NO;
    }

    x = (10.0f * x) + [sender tag];

    [self showScreen];
}

- (IBAction)operation:(id)sender {

    if (yFlag && !xFlag) {

        switch (operation) {

        case OP_PLUS:
            x = y + x;
            break;

        case OP_MINUS:
            x = y - x;
            break;

        case OP_MULT:
            x = y * x;
            break;

        case OP_DIV:
            x = y / x;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    y = x;
    xFlag = YES;
    yFlag = YES;

    operation = [sender tag];

    [self showScreen];
}

- (void) showScreen {

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.12g", x];
    [displayLabel setText:str];

}

@end
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific about what is wrong with all of the code you posted.

Comment: The code works fine. I have no idea how to put a decimal point between digits. Theres is a button (IBAction)dot, asking for an advice how to implement it for my code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send dot to your display and separate numbers use this for your numbers and dot buttons:

```
 NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    [display setText: [[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit]];
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. If i use it for my dot button, it shows up a decimal point in my label, but when i enter another digit it overwrites it. It only displays number with decimal point, but i can't use it. My x variable still remains the same (if it displays 3.14, x = 314 still). I show the value of x using [self showScreen], my problem is to change the value.

Comment: I dont know if i realy understand what you want to do. Why you have your action for digit so complicate?